# Allow only .json requests on apache server using .htaccess

Tags: php, json, apache, .htaccess

I have an underdeveloped website which is live on the net now (need remote access). This site has both php/html output for human visitors and .json output for the API. Currently I want it this way that if a human visitor visits the site, he/she will be redirect to a coming soon page. but if the request contains .json, it will be delivered. Note: the json requests on the api looks like:

```
example.com/../..../example.json
example.com/../../example.json/all/etc
```

Is there any way using .htaccess I can achieve such functionality? Thanks

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are determining a *human" simply by they fact `.json` exists in the url?

Comment: Right now if the url does not contain .json, then yes they'll be redirected to welcome page. (.json resources are pass protected, only developers with token can access them). But I was wondering if I redirect the normal requests to a coming soon page

Comment: You can check based on the url containing .json, but I believe it'd be better to check based on something else, such as an http header set for the API calls.

Comment: Yes that's what I am thinking to do (check the urls containing .json). But I am not familiar with ,htaccess syntax, Tried some examples, but no luck. But I am sure only 1/2 lines can make what I am willing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in order to allow access only to URLs containing ".json", and show a coming_soon.htm page otherwise, use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.json
RewriteRule ^.* coming_soon.htm [L]
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it as soon as I get back to my pc (on a cellphone right now). But one note that all urls with json does not end with .json, some of them have arguments with it like (example.com/../../example.json/all/etc)
Is this code still gonna work with those too? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will. that's why there's no `$` sign after the `.json`.

Comment: This code almost works, But it is redirecting both normal requests and .json requests to coming_soon.htm :(

Comment: Do you have any other RewriteCond/Rules on that .htaccess? Try also with `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`

Comment: There are other .htaccess rules too but these lines are at first. i tried to use another fresh .htaccess, but no luck. A json request of my site
http://lutmaar.com:8081/deals-online-service.json/all/all